# Cocoa QTKit resolution problem

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

Based on a lot of online references, the way to change resolution is using the following code.

```
NSDictionary * pixelBufferAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:320], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:240], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
     [NSNumbernumberWithBool:YES], 
                  (id)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey,
     [NSNumber 
        numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8],
                  (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                        nil];

NSArray *outputsConnected = [mCaptureSession outputs];

QTCaptureVideoPreviewOutput * previewOutput = [outputsConnected objectAtIndex:1];

[previewOutput setDelegate:self];

[previewOutput setPixelBufferAttributes:pixelBufferAttr];
```

But after changing the resolution, the `captureView` can see the different, but using code to check the resolution is incorrect.

Does anyone know how to change the device resolution?

Thanks ALL!

Comment: Wait a minute: Are you saying that you try to change the attributes of the previewOutput of a `QTCaptureView`?

Comment: Do you know how to change the device resolution, on the internet is only found the method to change the preview output and decompress output, but no actual device. Plx help.